# Snapping in ArcPy gives RuntimeError

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python

This line:

```
arcpy.Snap_edit("vst", [["ps_vst", "VERTEX", "0.02 meters"], ["ps_vst", "EDGE", "0.03 meters"]])
```

gives:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\edit.py", line 221, in Snap
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Same thing returned, also I tried removing the Meters and the quotes with just the number and didn't work either

Comment: Yes, it even suggested the names of the files

Comment: I changed environment to test other files. and it worked and then changed it back to this and it worked. Maybe, memory flushed and solved it?

Comment: That's *really* not a helpful error message. When using Snap_edit be sure you have a standard or advanced license, you can check this with if arcpy.ProductInfo() not in ['ArcInfo','ArcEditor']: sys.exit(-1) # to terminate the program.. use arcpy.AddError('License not suitable') prior to the sys.exit() to give a bit of info (in red text) to explain the sudden bail out.